# Debugging web API back-end and angular front-end as two projects in one solution

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, routes, asp.net-web-api

I have one solution in Visual Studio 2013 which contains MVC Web API and Angular app.
I have set Multiple Startup Projects so both projects start in the same time when debugging.
The both start OK, but they are running on different ports so there is no way for front-end to call api from back-end.

front-end has request look like this:

```
$http.get("api/MenuItems").then(function(response) {
    //do something here
});
```

and backend has controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/MenuItems")]
public class MenuController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        return Ok(MenuItem.GetItems());
    }
}
```

How do I debug this? I would like to set breakpoint in the controller of the Web API and see the debugger stop when fron-tend fire up request, but this never happens ... Am I missing something?

This was inspired by tutorial [AngularJS Token Authentication using ASP.NET Web API 2, Owin, and Identity](http://bitoftech.net/2014/06/09/angularjs-token-authentication-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin-asp-net-identity/)

Source code for the tutoprial is [tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication](https://github.com/tjoudeh/AngularJSAuthentication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they are running on different ports, you have to specify the full url. A full url goes http(s)://host:port/address

So if your backend server was on port 80, you should have your api call
http://localhost:80/api/menuItems

When a url is relative it will go to the same host so if your frontend was on port 40, /api/menuItems refers to
http://localhost:40/api/menuItems

Then if you are debugging web api and you put a breakpoint at the start of the controller function Get() you should be able to debug the request

Comment: so for debuging purposes the address needs to be hardcoded? is there no way around it?

Comment: Yes. If you use a build system like grunt you can make the url a parameter so that build_test uses the localhost url and build uses the relative one. Fundamentally it cannot discover the address for itself unless it is on the same port. Alternatively you can put an if statement in your code that uses the hardcode url for testing. Please accept answer if it works.

Comment: using hardcoded server address with port worked. I just thought there will be more clever way arround. thnks for help!

Answer (score 0):

There is an article for similar to this.
https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/Dec/15/Debugging-ApplicationStart-and-Module-Initialization-with-IIS-and-Visual-Studio

Basically if you want to be able to debug AngularJS and MVC server side code at the same time(F5 in Visual Studio), you need to configure the website in IIS. So serverside and client side can call the same domain(not with the port).